# Android configuration folder conflict?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-4.4-kitkat

Suppose I have a value for the margin of a view that varies depending on screen sizes. So `values-ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, large, xlarge`. This works well. Now suppose I want the values to be slightly altered for devices running Android 4.4. If I add the same `dimens.xml` in `values-v19` folder with one slightly altered variable, which `dimens.xml` would a device running the app consider? The value from the screen sizes folder or the android version folder?

Note that I need to add extra margin on Android 4.4 because I have transparent status bar and hence the layout needs to be under the actionbar as well as the status bar. It is possible programmatically but that would require a lot of work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**More Detail:**
I require that the action bar be translucent for all Android versions including 4.4, and the status bar to be translucent for 4.4 as well. Navigation bar should be transparent/translucent too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: For your end result, your solution should be to set both `fitsSystemWindows="true"` and `clipToPadding="false"` on your `ScrollView`. This will ensure that enough padding is set to put the content within the system bars, but will allow the contents to scroll away underneath.

---

Check Table 2 [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources), and you can see in what order of precedence the qualifiers will be matched.

In your case, the screen size takes precedence over the Android version, so if you had:

```
res/
    values-large/
        dimens.xml
            padding_value = 40dp
    values-v19/
        dimens.xml
            padding_value = 48dp
```

And tried to use that dimension on a large screen KitKat device, `40dp` would be the resolved value.

EDIT: For what you need, just set the attribute `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on the root of your layout -- that will handle insetting the content for the translucent status bar and/or navigation bar automatically. :)

Comment: I DO have android:fitsSystemWindows="true" but I still need to add the top margin for StatusBar+ActionBar as well as bottom margin for NavigationBar. I don't know why it is not working. I also have requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY) for ActionBar. Would this be causing this issue?

Comment: Yup! That would be the cause. The overlay flag tells it that it's okay to draw over your content. I'd take that flag away and everything should work.

Comment: Didn't fix it :( I still need to add margin for ActionBar+StatusBar. I have a DrawerLayout as the main layout and android:fitsSystemWindows="true" is added to the DrawerLayout View if it this information matters..

Comment: See my recent edit. I haven't worked with DrawerLayout so I'm not sure what your hierarchy looks like, exactly, but what you can do is have a base layout without fitsSystemWindows set, and in that layout, place your fullscreen content, and then another layout with fitsSystemWindows set, and inside that layout place the content that should stay within the ActionBar/Status/Navbar bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. What I need is A ScrollView to be be displayed under the actionbar to start with. But when scrolling down, the contents should appear behind the translucent actionbar and statusbar.

Comment: Then your ScrollView should have `fitsSystemWindows` set to true, but `clipToPadding` set to false.

Comment: :O this was so easy!!! You are the best person in the world. I would one day like to marry you. :D

Comment: Haha, glad it helped! Insets can be a bit tricky at first. :)

Comment: @NeilDA I've cleaned up the answer and added the solution from the comments if you'd like to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have folders like `values-ldpi`, `values-mdpi`, .... and also `values-ldpi-v19`, `values-mdpi-v19`, .... and so on. Here is a link for more information about [configuration qualifier names](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules).

Comment: I assume this would require me to add 5 another sets of folder with values-<screenSize>-v19. Hmmm... if there is no easier way then I'll go with this